# Options for reading a remote directory

Tags: php, parsing, directory

I have a script that displays images based on certain conditions. When none of the conditions are met, I want to randomly display one of the standard (backup) images. Those other images are on a remote server. I have read that you can't read a directory on a remote server, which makes sense.

Is my best bet to place a file into the remote server's image directory that outputs all of the image file names so I can parse it with the other server? Is there an easier way?

I prefer not to use FTP (http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php).

What are my options for basically just getting the names of the images in that folder?

Thanks,
Ryan

**UPDATE:**

@[mario's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902985/options-for-reading-a-remote-directory/4903065#4903065) is lightweight and works like a charm. It is exactly the solution I thought I wanted, but after thinking about it some more, and reading that even @mario would do it differently, I decided to go with @[bensiu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902985/options-for-reading-a-remote-directory/4903025#4903025), because to me, control and security are more important than convenience. With @mario's method, it's very hard to know if the data you're getting is any good (lack of control) and you're exposing your directory / some server information (security). @bensiu's suggestion involves a second file (inconvenience), but provides the control and security I'm ultimately deciding to go with!

Thank you both!

-Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you at least have access to remote server...

You can place there script "A" that will do the job locally, return list of images in preffered format ( raw text, JSON, XML... ), and this script will be remotly called by curl form your server....

It also wise to make sure that when you call script "A" you at least passing some secret key to prevent unathorised access (not perfect solution but could be enought)

Comment: That definitely sounds like solid approach. I wanted to try to keep the remote server as uninvolved as possible, because I never know what kind of remote servers I will be dealing with in the future, but your approach still may be the best one from what I've seen so far.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer an exact and dedicated handler script like @bensiu pointed out.

But an alternative would be to read out a directory listing. A simple Apache generated mod_index listing would be sufficient for:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com/images/");
preg_match_all('/<a href="([-\w\d.]+\.(jpeg|png|gif))"/', $html, $uu);
$files = $uu[1];
```

Comment: hmmm... are you sure that you will get list of files not default page in this folder ?

Comment: @bensiu: Obviously you'll need to get rid of any stub or empty index.html, and if directory listings are disabled it's a no-go as well. One could configure it at an obscure location, but then a simple `<?=json_encode(glob("*.jpeg"))?>` script would be easier to setup there.

Comment: Directory listings are by default disabled, but I enabled them for that directory via an .htaccess file.

Comment: @RyanS: Well, no idea with exact infos. Above snippet works for me, but the regex has to be relaxed for other filename variations.

Comment: I gave it another shot and it worked. You mentioned you also preferred a dedicated handler on the remote server, is there a downfall to using the method you describe here?

Comment: @Ryan: Well this approach depends on the Apache configuration. And it exposes directory listings as-is. Whereas a handler script could be "hidden" or even password protected. (Though I'd say this is not usually a serious issue; often just overcautiosness.)

Comment: Interesting... I'm also finding out that it's a pain in the *** to validate, because how do you know that there's good data on that page... :)

Answer (score 0):

if you have PHP5 and the HTTP stream wrapper enabled on your server, it's very easy and simple to copy it to a local file:

```
copy('http://somedomain.com/file.jpeg', '/tmp/file.jpeg');
```

ome hosts disable copy() function then you can make your own -

```
<?php 
    function copyemz($file1,$file2){ 
          $contentx =@file_get_contents($file1); 
                   $openedfile = fopen($file2, "w"); 
                   fwrite($openedfile, $contentx); 
                   fclose($openedfile); 
                    if ($contentx === FALSE) { 
                    $status=false; 
                    }else $status=true; 

                    return $status; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: ultimately he wants to also display them . "When none of the conditions are met, I want to randomly display one of the standard (backup) images". this is there in question.

Comment: in order to display you do not need to copy - link is enougth

Comment: To copy $file1 to $file2, I would have to know the path of $file1, which is what I'm trying to do. How did you get the path?